# Java Web Application Failed to run as maven project

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I am new to java . I am using apache netbeans 12.2 version to create new project and the java version is 17 . I followed the step to create java web application with maven but when I build it and try to run it I am getting following errors in the console window.

**Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project JavaProject: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null**

I checked in pom.xml file the required dependency already there , But why it not able to run?.

Here is the Pom.xml code .

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>JavaProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>JavaProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT</name>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>8.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
     <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
           
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the entire console with error message.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project JavaProject: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.3/maven-war-plugin-2.3.jar
urls[1] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
urls[2] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
urls[3] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar
urls[4] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
urls[5] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar
urls[6] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.5/plexus-io-2.0.5.jar
urls[7] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.2/plexus-archiver-2.2.jar
urls[8] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.15/plexus-interpolation-1.15.jar
urls[9] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
urls[10] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.3/xstream-1.4.3.jar
urls[11] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/xmlpull/xmlpull/1.1.3.1/xmlpull-1.1.3.1.jar
urls[12] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar
urls[13] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.8/plexus-utils-3.0.8.jar
urls[14] = file:/Users/mohammadhossan/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------
: ExceptionInInitializerError: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @73bb1337
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Java is incompatible with your version of NetBeans because NetBeans 12.2 does not support the use of JDK 17. From the NetBeans 12.2 Release notes [Downloading Apache NetBeans 12.2](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb122/nb122.html):

> Apache NetBeans 12.2 runs on JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, as well as on
> JDK 15, i.e., the current JDK release at the time of this NetBeans
> release.

In general, when changing your version of NetBeans and/or Java, make sure that the versions are compatible. This is always documented in the NetBeans release notes.

You have two options to resolve this:

- Upgrade to NetBeans 12.6 which supports Java 17.
- Stay on NetBeans 12.2, but downgrade to Java 15 or lower. That is, make JDK 15 (or lower) your default platform for NetBeans 12.2.

Of course you may also have other issues with your project, but there is no point in worrying about those until you have fixed this problem.

Comment: Netbeans 12.4 Release notes say it supports JDK 8, 11, and 16 still when I'm installing 12.4, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @Shubham OK. In that case please create a new question with supporting evidence since comments are not the appropriate way to resolve new problems. But note that this question relates to project creation. Since you state that your problem relates to the installation of NetBeans it is qualitatively different to this one, and I don't understand how you could be getting the "same error" (with a Maven project) as the OP when "installing 12.4". That doesn't make sense. (But perhaps I'm misunderstanding you, which is another reason why comments are not a good place for resolving problems!)